# dynamically add and remove sockets

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

How would I add / remove sockets dynamically on the with / as statement. Or would i need a completely other aproach like asyncio.create_task?

```
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient, BinanceSocketManager

api_key = config.binance_key
api_secret = config.binance_secret



async def main():
    client = await AsyncClient.create()
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)

    # start any sockets here, i.e a trade socket
    ts1 = bm.symbol_ticker_socket('BNBBTC')
    ts2 = bm.symbol_ticker_socket('ETHBUSD')

    # then start receiving messages
    async with ts1 as tscm1, ts2 as tscm2:
        while True:
            res1 = await tscm1.recv()
            res2 = await tscm2.recv()
            print(res1)
            print(res2)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`AsyncExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.AsyncExitStack) to combine and handle multiple asynchronous context managers.
An auxiliary coroutine `read_ticker` is used to read data from a ticker socket connection.

```
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient, BinanceSocketManager
from contextlib import AsyncExitStack

api_key = config.binance_key
api_secret = config.binance_secret


async def read_ticker(ts_cm):
    """Read ticker data from ticker socket connection"""
    while True:
        res = await ts_cm.recv()
        print(res)

async def main():
    client = await AsyncClient.create()
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)

    # start any sockets here, i.e a trade socket
    ts1 = bm.symbol_ticker_socket('BNBBTC')
    ts2 = bm.symbol_ticker_socket('ETHBUSD')

    async with AsyncExitStack() as stack:
        await asyncio.gather(*[read_ticker(await stack.enter_async_context(ts))
                               for ts in (ts1, ts2)])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```